# Codeigniter non-object model function

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Model File:

```
Class productModel extends CI_Model{

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
  function getProduct() {

    $query =  $this->db->get('urunler');
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

Controller file:

```
class product extends CI_Controller {


  public function index()
  {
            $model= $this->load->model('productModel',NULL,TRUE);
            $data['urunListesi']=$model->getProduct();

    $this->load->view("site/header");
            $this->load->view("site/product",$data);
            $this->load->view("site/footer");
  }
}
```

and view file:

```
foreach ($urunListele as $value) {


                         $adi=$value["adi"];
                         $fotolik= $value['fotolink'];
                         $kucukfot=$value["kucukfoto"];
                         $hakkinda = $value["hakkinda"];

                          echo "<div class='portfolio-item logo animation col-md-3'>";
                                  echo  "<div class='portfolio-border'>";
                                  //<!-- Start Portfolio Item Thumb -->
                                  echo "<div class='portfolio-thumb'>";
                                      echo "<a class='lightbox' title='$hakkinda' href='$fotolik'> ";
                                          echo "<div class='thumb-overlay'><i class='icon-resize-full'></i></div>";
                                          echo "<img alt='' src='$kucukfot' />";
                                      echo "</a>";
                                  echo "</div>";

                                 echo " <div class='portfolio-details'>";

                                          echo "<h4>";
                                          echo "<p align='center'>" . $value["adi"]. "</p>";
                                          echo "</h4>";

                                  echo "</div>";

                              echo "</div>";
                          echo "</div>";
}
```

And I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ModaGabar\application\controllers\product.php on line 9
```

I do this also:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Comment: Look at the view too, this assignment might bite you later, `$fotolik= $value['fotolink'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your product class have a constructor ?
if it doesn't add:

```
public function __construct() {        
    parent::__construct();
}
```

if it does try removing the null parameter :

```
$model= $this->load->model('productModel',NULL,TRUE);
```

Change it to:

```
$model= $this->load->model('productModel','',TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of loading models and referencing them is wrong. The second argument of loading function is used to assign object to a name other than the model name. Additionally, you are referencing the model by using the variable to make calls when the loading function itself returns nothing.

So, what you would need to do is, load the model.

```
$this->load->model('productModel');
```

To make calls you would have to use,

```
$this->productModel->method();
```

or

You can use another object name via the second parameter.

```
$this->load->model('productModel', 'pmodel');
```

To make calls you would have to use,

```
$this->pmodel->method();
```

Comment: In addition, `this->load->model()` does not return a value, so you can not store it in a variable.